# how to instruct Snakemake to download "directory" type input from GCS bucket in cloud execution (K8s/GKE)

Tags: google-cloud-storage, snakemake

I am trying to make a tutorial pipeline to run on GKE.[LINK](https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/snakemake-novice-bioinformatics/06-awkward_programs/index.html)

The specific rules that failed are

```
rule salmon_quant:
    output: directory("salmon.{sample}")
    input:
        index = "Saccharomyces_cerevisiae.R64-1-1.salmon_index",
        fq1   = "trimmed/{sample}_1.fq",
        fq2   = "trimmed/{sample}_2.fq",
    shell:
        "salmon quant -i {input.index} -l A -1 {input.fq1} -2 {input.fq2} --validateMappings -o {output}"

rule salmon_index:
    output:
        idx = directory("{strain}.salmon_index")
    input:
        fasta = "transcriptome/{strain}.cdna.all.fa.gz"
    shell:
        "salmon index -t {input.fasta} -i {output.idx} -k 31"
```

The error I got from the log of the pod shows:

```
Downloading from remote: smk_demo/trimmed/ref_3_2.fq
Finished download.
Downloading from remote: smk_demo/Saccharomyces_cerevisiae.R64-1-1.salmon_index
Finished download.
Downloading from remote: smk_demo/trimmed/ref_3_1.fq
Finished download.
Activating conda environment: .snakemake/conda/c7537b64e219a0e5525266c7cc140f93_
Version Info: Could not resolve upgrade information in the alotted time.
Check for upgrades manually at https://combine-lab.github.io/salmon
### salmon (mapping-based) v1.2.1
#
# other salmon output omitted 
#
[2023-07-26 05:28:49.492] [jointLog] [info] There is 1 library.
Exception : [Error: The index version file smk_demo/Saccharomyces_cerevisiae.R64-1-1.salmon_index/versionInfo.json doesn't seem to exist.  Please try re
salmon quant was invoked improperly.
```

I checked inside the container:

```
k exec -it snakejob-21242d20-1417-50c4-a83b-8e5e4ae5f8d3 -- ls /workdir/smk_demo/Saccharomyces_cerevisiae.R64-1-1.salmon_index/
ls: cannot access '/workdir/smk_demo/Saccharomyces_cerevisiae.R64-1-1.salmon_index/': Not a directory
command terminated with exit code 2
```

I confirmed that the directory (and the files inside) generated by rule `salmon_index` did get uploaded to the bucket.

Since GCS bucket does not really has "directory". I think the cause is when:
`Downloading from remote: smk_demo/Saccharomyces_cerevisiae.R64-1-1.salmon_index`
It was downloaded as a file.

I tried adding a tailing `/` at the end of the input:
`index = "Saccharomyces_cerevisiae.R64-1-1.salmon_index/",`
It does not help.

I am using snakemake 7.28.3, I could not find any bugs or tickets that match my issue.

Since the directory() is applicable only to output, not input. So I don't know if there is another way to let snakemake know it needs to download the input from GCS as a directory?